Alignment key not working for each first line of a word document pages
The first line of each new page in ms word is centered by default. It doesn't change while the align-left mark is on. The Align keys are not working on the first line of every page. What can I do to left-align the top line of each page of the document?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
